# SQL Code to receive complete list of locations based on ocurrence in other table

Tags: sql

I'm trying to write a SQL code that returns a complete list of all locations ordered by the occurrence of in another list.

LOCATIONS being the index table of all locations in the application
OFFERS being the table containing information about offers, including the field OFFERS.location

Currently, I have this code:

```
select
    l.default_name
from
    OFFERS o
inner join LOCATIONS l on
    l.id = o.location_id
group by
    l.default_name
order by
    count(o.location_id) desc,
    l.default_name asc
```

This query returns me a list of the most used locations in OFFERS, with a secondary ordering in alphabetic order in case two locations have the same occurrence.

My problem is that the query returns only the locations that have at least one record in OFFERS. I could not manage to find out how to append the remaining locations from LOCATIONS that are not present in OFFERS. (LOCATIONS has 10000 entries, only 300 are currently present in OFFERS)

I hope you can help me.

Best,
Dean

EDIT: SOLUTION BELOW

Comment: Do an outer join to include all locations.

Answer (score 0):

Here the working code:

```
SELECT
    l2.location_name
FROM
    T_LOCATIONS l2
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT
        count(o.location_id) 'count',
        l.id 'id'
    FROM
        OFFERS o
    INNER JOIN LOCATIONS l ON
        l.id = o.location_id
    GROUP BY
        o.default_name) top ON
    top.id = l2.id
ORDER BY
    top.count(o.location_id) DESC,
    l2.default_name;
```